# Get JSON of an 1:n relationship with json_object (Oracle)

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a simple 1:n relationship in Oracle version 21 XE. E.g.:

```
    CREATE TABLE parent (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE child (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id)
);

insert into parent (id, last_name) values (1, 'Mom');
insert into child (id, parent_id, name) values (1, 1, 'Kid 1');
insert into child (id, parent_id, name) values (2, 1, 'Kid 2');
insert into child (id, parent_id, name) values (3, 1, 'Kid 3');
```

I can almost get it as JSON with the following:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(parent.*, 'children' value json_array(json_object (child.*))) FROM Parent, Child WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id and parent.id = 1;
```

This yields:

```
{"ID":1,"LAST_NAME":"Mom","children":[{"ID":1,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 1"}]}
{"ID":1,"LAST_NAME":"Mom","children":[{"ID":2,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 2"}]}
{"ID":1,"LAST_NAME":"Mom","children":[{"ID":3,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 3"}]}
```

However, I would like to have all 3 children that are related via the foreign key as part of the JSON array (not 3 separate results).
In other words, something like:

```
{"ID":1,"LAST_NAME":"Mom","children":[{"ID":1,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 1"},
                                      {"ID":2,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 2"},
                                      {"ID":3,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 3"}]}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to aggregate the children and then join to the parent:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
          p.*,
          'children' VALUE c.children
       ) AS json
FROM   Parent p 
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT parent_id,
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) AS children
         FROM   Child
         GROUP BY parent_id
       ) c
       ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE  p.id = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| JSON |
| --- |
| {"ID":1,"LAST_NAME":"Mom","children":[{"ID":1,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 1"},{"ID":3,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 3"},{"ID":2,"PARENT_ID":1,"NAME":"Kid 2"}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vh-RYE9K)